# Translate mongo nested array query into mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following query working with mongo, it returns the expected result

```
db.getCollection('trainings').find({"sections.employees.employee":ObjectId("5d3afa1a58a7160ea451d1db")})
```

but when I try the following call with mongoose, it returns an empty array

```
Training.find({'section.employees.employee': "5d3afa1a58a7160ea451d1db"})
```

Need some helping to translate the mongo query to mongoose.

If you need anything else just add a comment and I will post here.

It's worth mentioning that I have already tried passing a new ObjectId with the String value, but it also returns an empty array.

Edit: Query usage

```
        return await Training.find({'section.employees.employee': "5d3afa1a58a7160ea451d1db"})
```

Edit: Model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const EmployeeSection = new Schema({
    employee: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Employee', required: true},
    fulfilled: {type: Boolean, default: null},
});

const Section = new Schema({
    order: {type: Number, required: true},
    date: {type: Date},
    employees: {type: [EmployeeSection]},
    answers: {type: Number},
    hits: {type: Number}
});

const GoalSchema = new Schema({
    understanding: {type: Number, required: true},
    fixation: {type: Number, required: true}
});


const Evidence = new Schema({
    description: {type: String, required: true},
    file: {type: String}
});

const Question = new Schema({
    participants: {type: Number},
    answers: {type: Number},
    hits: {type: Number}
});

const TrainingSchema = new Schema({
    company: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company', required: true, index: true},
    creationDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    title: {type: String},
    obs: {type: String},
    questionNumber: {type: Number},
    reference: {type: String},
    sections: {type: [Section]},
    goals: {
        answers: {type: GoalSchema, required: true},
        hits: {type: GoalSchema, required: true}
    },
    evidences: {type: [Evidence]},
    questions: {type: [Question]},
    area: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'TrainingArea', required: true},
});


const Training = mongoose.model('Training', TrainingSchema);


module.exports = Training;
```

I am willing to change the Model schema, if the problem really lays there, but didn't really want to do it.

Comment: How did you use that query in your code?

Comment: Please show your schema as well

Comment: Both there, tanks

Comment: Need a document example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why its always a typo?

```
db.getCollection('trainings').find({"sections.employees.employee":ObjectId("5d3afa1a58a7160ea451d1db")})


Training.find({'section.employees.employee': "5d3afa1a58a7160ea451d1db"})
```

Forgot s on sections

Answer (score 0):

Made the problem a bit easier for me.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/training", { useNewUrlParser: true })
const util = require("util")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const EmployeeSection = new Schema({
    employee: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Employee', required: true}
});

const Section = new Schema({
    employees: {type: [EmployeeSection]}
});

const TrainingSchema = new Schema({
    sections: {type: [Section]}
});


const Training = mongoose.model('Training', TrainingSchema);



Training.find(
    {
            "sections.employees.employee": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5d3afa1a58a7160ea451d1db")
    })
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
        console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null, true /* enable colors */))
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Comment: This should also work, but the problem was a typo, StackOverflow doesn't let me accept my answer till 2 days have passed, maybe I should delete the question ...